# How do I write a program that will interact with an app on my computer? (I.e feed it input)

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, and I'm trying write a program (i'll call it p1)  that will generate random 16-digit numbers and enter them into another program (lets say p2) I have on my computer. The goal is to for p1 to keep entering a new number into p2 until it the correct number is entered.

I understand how to generate numbers and what not but I don't know how to make it so p1 enters the numbers automatically instead of having to do it manually. Basically I don't know hoe to get the two programs to interact?

Comment: What kind of an app?  Is it a GUI app, or a console app?  You're aware that there isn't enough time in the sun's lifetime to try 10,000,000,000,000,000 brute force attempts?

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get two scripts to interact, you can use subprocess.Popen, more info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. I'm not sure what you mean by programs, but an example of how you could get two scripts to interact would be:

p1:

```
import subprocess
import random as r

random_num = int((r.random())*99) # 2 digit number
s = subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:/Users/Jhanz/PycharmProjects/test/p2.py", str(random_num)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while s.stdout.read() != b"Congratulations! You guessed the number!\r\n":
    random_num = int((r.random()) * 99)
    s = subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:/Users/Jhanz/PycharmProjects/test/p2.py", str(random_num)],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print("You guessed the number!", random_num)
```

p2:

```
import sys

number_to_guess = 10
if int(sys.argv[1]) == number_to_guess:
    print("Congratulations! You guessed the number!")
else:
    print("You didn't guess the number!")
```